# How do you efficiently pass object properties?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, properties, parameters

I have a question regarding passing properties in Actionscript 3.0. The current setup I have is this.

```
ballObject(name:String,imageID:String,category:String,price:Number,description:String,priority:String)
```

I'm getting these values from an XML file. As you can see it looks awful. I was wondering if there is another way to do this, what design approach would be better?  I'm looking also for a more dynamic approach. Right now if I want to add a new value it seems pretty hard coded in.

EDIT:
Oh yeah I'm loading these objects with a BallManager class, that's why I'm passing parameters. Would it be smarter to to just let the ballObjects get their properties from the XML by themselves or keep the ballManager passing parameters?

Comment: you can make a model class with all properties and pass into your ballObject function the model. Or maybe you can pass the xml node in your object. without more code, it's hard to say more

Comment: Passing the whole node seems like a great idea! I can't believe I have never thought of that! Could you provide it as an answer? I apologize that the question has little to do with code. It's more of a structure/method problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an XML string or object into a constructor, then retrieve properties inside the class constructor. As you already have an XML, you can use that, or a part of the XML-parsed object to be the source of properties. Then you just add one line of code to the constructor if you need another property.

```
public function BallObject(source:Object) {
    this.name=source.name;
    this.imageID=source.imageID;
    // etc
}
```

You call it with a parsed XML object, say you've got an array of objects in the XML, and parse it via XML constructor, thus your XML object has an array named say `balls`. You then do like this:

```
for (var i:int=0;i<xml.balls.length;i++) {
    var ball:BallObject=new BallObject(xml.balls[i]);
    // process ball
}
```